# Exporting a Opus stream to a wav file in Rust

Tags: rust, ogg, opus

I've gotten a Opus stream (specifically one from Discord voice servers), and I'm trying to convert it to a .wav file that can be used for DeepSpeech. I've already done some internet digging, and found `opusdec`, which almost perfectly fits my use case. I exported some test files to test upon, but when I tried to use them with `opusdec`, I got a error:

```
$ opusdec 293434418808314550478788892773147202909.opus 
Decoding complete.        
This doesn't look like a Opus file
```

(the file used above can be downloaded [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/796094282279813150/834292630392537179/293434418808314550478788892773147202909.opus))

I know these files have no Ogg container in them, so what I'm mainly looking for is a nice way to create a .opus file with a Ogg container in Rust. All the libraries I have found so far seem to be poorly documented, and given how long compiling a test program on my laptop takes, I'm reluctant to do the fiddling around required to use them.

So far, to convert the files to .wav, I've tried using `ffmpeg` with multiple types of formats passed in (`-f s16be`, `-f libopus`) but they either threw a error or resulted in valid wav files, but with static as their contents.

I'm open to a completely different way of doing this, if any are suggested.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, whatever the file is you've provided, it's not a valid opus file at all (tested with Tika):
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Supplied File is not Opus
 at org.gagravarr.opus.OpusFile.<init>(OpusFile.java:79)`

Comment: You can either use the [`opus`](https://crates.io/crates/opus) crate to decode the stream yourself, or use the [`ogg`](https://crates.io/crates/ogg) crate to wrap it in an ogg container that external tools will understand.

Comment: I'll try out the `opus` crate, seeing as that would mean I don't need to make any more changes to the rest of my code. Thanks!